# Combining all immediately previous rows that have the same value as last row in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks similar to this:

```
ID  Description
1  "Low Blood Sugar, High Temperature"
1  "No Appetite"
2  "Blood Test Taken"
2  "D4556 Applied, No Obvious Reaction"
3  "At Rest"
1  "Lower Temperature, Improving"
1  "Walked 50m"
1  "Sedated"
```

What I want to do is return as an array, the last patient ID and all comments that occurred to the same patient immediately previously. That is, not anything that happened earlier. For example, I want to return:

```
ID  Description
1  "Lower Temperature, Improving, Walked 50m, Sedated"
```

I can work this out with for loops, but I have a big dataframe and want something more efficient. I'm already subsetting over different variables using ddply, this is why I only need the last observations for the last ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a solution:

```
#use rle to get the number of rows for the last id
idrows <- rle(df$ID)$lengths[length(rle(df$ID)$lengths)]
#use rle in the same way to get the actual id value
id     <- rle(df$ID)$values[length(rle(df$ID)$values)]

#combine the above two variables to calculate the needed values
#i.e. the id and the pasted-together descriptions
> data.frame(id = id, Description = paste(df[(nrow(df)-idrows+1):nrow(df), 'Description'], 
                                          collapse=','))

  id                                     Description
1  1 Lower Temperature, Improving,Walked 50m,Sedated
```

Just to make it a bit more clear, `df[(nrow(df)-idrows+1):nrow(df), 'Description']` selects the last rows for the needed id and `paste` pastes those descriptions together.

Comment: Using a combination of your answer and docendo discimus's I managed to get pretty good efficiency, but you're the only one who explicitly answered my question (that I needed only the LAST descriptions from the LAST id) so I'll give you the tick. Thanks for your help and clear solution.

Comment: Thanks @BorisCocker. You are welcome, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

Another `data.table` approach (using `rleid`):

```
library(data.table) #1.9.6
res <- setDT(df)[, list(ID[1L], toString(Description)), by = rleid(ID)]
```

You can remove the `rleid` column later on using

```
res[, rleid := NULL]
```

---

If you only want to return the last `ID` in aggregated form, you could do the following which should be pretty quick:

```
idx <- df[,rleid(ID)]
df[idx == max(idx), list(ID[1L], toString(Description))]
#   V1                                                V2
#1:  1 Lower Temperature, Improving, Walked 50m, Sedated
```

Comment: @BorisCocker, please see my updated answer. Apparently I misunderstood your expected output at first

Answer (score 1):

First we create a unique id by group in column ID:

```
df$id <- cumsum(c(1, diff(df$ID)!=0))

  ID                        Description id
1  1  Low Blood Sugar, High Temperature  1
2  1                        No Appetite  1
3  2                   Blood Test Taken  2
4  2 D4556 Applied, No Obvious Reaction  2
5  3                            At Rest  3
6  1       Lower Temperature, Improving  4
7  1                         Walked 50m  4
8  1                            Sedated  4
```

Then we select the last rows meeting the condition and create the vector:

```
c(t(df[df$id==max(df$id),][2]))
```

Output:

```
[1] "Lower Temperature, Improving" "Walked 50m" "Sedated"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table` you can try:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
dt[,list(ID=ID[1],Description=paste(Description,collapse=", ")),
    by=cumsum(c(TRUE,df$ID[2:nrow(df)]!=df$ID[1:(nrow(df)-1)]))][,
    list(ID,Description)]   
#ID                                             Description
#1:  1       Low Blood Sugar, High Temperature, No Appetite
#2:  2 Blood Test Taken, D4556 Applied, No Obvious Reaction
#3:  3                                              At Rest
#4:  1    Lower Temperature, Improving, Walked 50m, Sedated
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this old question already has an accepted answer, I felt challenged to add another `data.table` solution which uses `rleid()` but is different to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32761411/3817004):

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
setDT(DF)[, .(ID, Description = toString(Description)), by = rleid(ID)][, .SD[.N]]
#   rleid ID                                       Description
#1:     4  1 Lower Temperature, Improving, Walked 50m, Sedated
```

This returns the aggregated last entries concerning the very last patient ID as requested by the OP.

As already mentioned in the other answer, `rleid` can be removed by chaining `[, rleid := NULL]`.

Just to mention, we can retrieve the aggregated last entries *for each* patient ID with a slight modification:

```
setDT(DF)[, .(Description = toString(Description)), .(ID, rleid(ID))][, .SD[.N], ID]
#   ID rleid                                          Description
#1:  1     4    Lower Temperature, Improving, Walked 50m, Sedated
#2:  2     2 Blood Test Taken, D4556 Applied, No Obvious Reaction
#3:  3     3                                              At Rest
```

Note that it is not required to name the `by` parameter as long as it is the third unnamed parameter.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread(
  'ID  Description
1  "Low Blood Sugar, High Temperature"
1  "No Appetite"
2  "Blood Test Taken"
2  "D4556 Applied, No Obvious Reaction"
3  "At Rest"
1  "Lower Temperature, Improving"
1  "Walked 50m"
1  "Sedated"'
, data.table = FALSE)
```

Note that the parameter `data.table = FALSE` instructs `fread()` to return a data.frame to be in line with OP's specifications.